# How to reset subscription discount eligibility for google license test users

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

How to reset the subscription discount eligibility for Google Play license test users?

I encountered an issue while testing subscription discounts with Google in-app purchases: after a test user successfully pays for the discounted first month, they lose eligibility for the discount in subsequent months.

Despite reviewing the official documentation and attempting various methods, I haven't found a way to reset the user's discount eligibility. Currently, my only workaround is to create a new account for each test.

I'm seeking advice or solutions from the community to properly test subscription discount functionality. Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

(If you have any suggestions regarding this issue, please leave a comment below. Thank you!)